# chunk of data into fixed lengths chunks and then add a space and again add them all as a string

Tags: regex, list, join, ironpython, findall

I have got hex values as `a85b080040010000`. I want it to be as `a8 5b 08 00 40 01 00 00`. I have done it by using below code. But I have to work with very large data. So I want computed time to be very low.

```
import binascii
import re

filename = 'calc.exe'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.readline()

text = binascii.hexlify(content)
text1 = binascii.unhexlify(text)
length1 = 32
length2 = 16

list = re.findall('.{%d}' % length1, text)
list1 = re.findall('.{%d}' % length2, text1)

d = []
for i in range (0, len(list), 1):
    temp = ""
    l = re.findall('.{%d}' % length2, list[i])

    s = l[0]
    t = iter(s)
    temp += str(' '.join(a+b for a,b in zip(t, t)))

    temp += "  "

    s = l[1]
    t = iter(s)
    temp += str(' '.join(a+b for a,b in zip(t, t)))
    temp += "  | " + list1[i]
    print temp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do

```
x="a85b080040010000"
print re.sub(r"(.{2})",r"\1 ",x)
```

or

```
x="a85b080040010000"

print " ".join([i for i in re.split(r"(.{2})",x) if i])
```

Comment: Thanks Dude. I have another doubt. the text and text1 lengths are not same. I dont know why. Becoz we are converting the same hexified content. so it must be same right. Just help me figure it out.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: sry dude.. its not same for list and list1 sections....i just mentioned as text and text1 sections...

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy can you try and print `list` and `list1` and add in ur question

Comment: just replace readline with read and take the test case of calc in system32...
i got values as 58368 and 56996...

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy lenght of both the lists are different.`57408 56056`